# NSPredicate in NSFetchedResultsController throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have a UITableViewController using an NSFetchedResultsController.  If I remove the predicate, It works fine, but with the predicate, it throws bad access (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).  I enabled NSZombieEnabled, but that turned up nothing.  I'm using ARC.  I don't get it!  Please help.  Here's  my fetchedresultscontroller code  NOTE:  Changing my predicate to random simple predicates such as "unitNumber = nil" or "unitNumber LIKE %@", unString STILL CAUSES a crash, however commenting the predicate out entirely will not produce crash (But then I have all objects and no filter obviously):

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Unit" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"workTicket.appointment.scheduleRowPointer = %@", rp];
[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


// Sort Descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *unitNumberDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"unitNumber" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:unitNumberDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"addedToTicket" cacheName:nil];

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: I thought I was done with EXC_BAD_ACCESS With the advent of ARC... guess not...

Comment: What's the property definition for fetchedResultsController look like?

Comment: @synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

Comment: Above in .m, and in .h I have:  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController fetchedResultsController;

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

to :

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: +1, and I'm not sure why you're changing the fetched results controller's fetch request to begin with - the section ["The Fetch Request"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW34) in the NSFetchedResultsController docs have some words of warning about trying to modify that request.